# SSRS for Sharepoint, Images in a report from a Sharepoint List URL?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, url, image, ssrs-2008

Greetings Sabios,

I have several reports I run successfully where the data comes from a Sharepoint list in the form of an XML dataset. I am however having trouble with one. I have a report that pulls an image file onto the main body of the report. This data too comes from a Sharepoint list in the form of an XML dataset which sends me the URL to the jpeg or bmp or gif... whatever the case may be.

1. I can successfully pull this off in my own Visual Studio IDE.
2. My Local Report Server will render it as well
3. It won't run on my Sharepoint Report Server (My MOSS runs through https while my Shartpoint Report Server is http might this matter?)

**When I upload it to Sharepoint and run it through the Sharepoint Report Server, I get back EVERYTHING in the report Header and Footer (dataset text and embedded Images) but just a big RED X where the Main Image should be.** I have done everything the boards say:

A. I made sure the Unattended Execution Account is running on the Reports Server
B. I have insured the URL comes back in clean format (else the images wouldn't render locally either and they do)

The report logs throw this exception:

*e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ContainerTypeNotSupportedException: The target location you specified is not supported by the report server. A report definition (.rdl), report model (.smdl), resource, or shared data source (.rsds) file must be located within a library or a folder within it., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ContainerTypeNotSupportedException: The target location you specified is not supported by the report server. A report definition (.rdl), report model (.smdl), resource, or shared data source (.rsds) file must be located within a library or a folder within it.*

Any takers? Even my Sharepoint Administrator can't help me:)

James

Comment: Still swimming on this one for the last 6 days

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the URL, just add the column to your report:

```
select leafname, [content]
from alldocstreams s
 inner join alldocs d on d.id = s.id
where
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the fix for THIS situation....

Display External Images SSRS-MOSS

You have an Image in Sharepoint that you want to display as an external image in a report through SQL Server reporting Services in Sharepoint Integration Mode. Simple you think... slow down. What your Visual Studio and Local Report Server display does not necessarily sit well with Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server.

**Do the following** for this is what THEY (the gurus of the web) will tell you for the most part:

A. Try to deceive MOSS, ignore dummy parameters =Fields!DocumentPath.Value &"&dummy=1"

B. Change configurations of the Custom Data Source

C. Change Report Server to HTTPS also

D. Configure your List directory to run with anonymous user

D. Set the UseSessionCookies to 'False' in the ConfigurationInfo table

E. The unattended execution account must be initialized in the Report Server

**However in addition to the the the above for now.** If you want to render the following type of report, here are the hoops you leap through to get to the end result:

Ask Yourself:

1. You want to create a List in Sharepoint for the data pertaining to your report and bring that data into the report via an XML extension. **GOOD**
2. You want the Sharepoint List to include the URL of the Image you wish to display. **GOOD**
3. You decide to add the image as an attachment to the List and use THAT URL as the Images Location. **BAD! Danger Will Robinson!!!!**

This works fine in the Visual Studio Environment and on your Local Reports Server
In Sharepoint Integrated Reports Servers, for some reason, using the URL to the same List's ATTACHMENT is Unacceptable!
You must upload the Image somewhere else on the server and access it that way.

I uploaded my Images into a Shared Documents Folder and placed the URL of THAT location in the URL field of my Reports List.
When I went back to run the Report through the Sharepoint Server: It worked! The Images came in from the Shared Document Location when that URL was placed in the URL field of the List.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this - embedding the image wasn't working.  So I put the image in my report library and put an external link to the image in my report.  I am running SSRS in SharePoint Integrated mode, serving up over https.